# Google spreadsheet and Python - How to generate double quote JSON with gspread

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to transform a google spreadsheet to JSON data using gspread.

I figured out this blog [Google spreadsheets and Python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) and able to generate a piece of JSON data. However, the data are wrapped with single quotes.

As the JSON standards require double quotes, I need a way to make it.

I know that using str.replace to replace single quotes with double quotes would be a solution, but sometimes my cell contains contents with single quotes, so the quotes in a cell would also be replaced and this is not the right move.

Remarks: I am using Python 3, I need my spreadsheet to be private